# Pros and cons of using VPLS instead of using MPLS alone

Tags: lan, mpls, wan, vpls

What are the pros and cons of using VPLS instead of MPLS alone?
What are the typical cases where VPLS is used?

Comment: Read This....https://luminet.co.uk/mpls-vs-vpls-right-solution-business/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really can't compare the pros and cons.  These are different (but related) technologies and they have been developed for a particular problem.  You might as well ask what are the pros and cons of using a hammer *vs.* a drill.

VPLS can be used when you want to extend your layer-2 topology over multiple sites.

Answer (score 0):

luminet.co.uk/mpls-vs-vpls-right-solution-business